# MongoDB & Symfony 6: Doctrine/mongodb-orm could not installed (Docker)

Tags: mongodb, docker, symfony

I'm trying to connect my Symfony 6 project with the MongoDB database on the Docker environment but when I launch the following command

```
composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm
```

This message appears

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.8] require symfony/console ~2.3|~3.0 -> found symfony/console[v2.3.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (6.1.*).
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.1.0, ..., 1.3.7] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires doctrine/mongodb-odm ^1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.7].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
        environment:
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/

    www:
        build: php
        container_name: www-docker-env
        ports:
            - '80:80'
        volumes: 
            - ./php/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
            - ./:/var/www
            -
                type: 'bind'
                source: '../project/'
                target: '/var/www/'
                consistency: 'delegated'
        restart: always
        networks: 
            - dev
networks: 
    dev:
volumes:
    mongo-data:
```

the Dockerfile file

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

ARG user
ARG uid

RUN echo 'ServerName localhost' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends locales apt-utils git libicu-dev g++ libpng-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev libonig-dev libxslt-dev \
    && apt install -y unzip;

RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && \
    echo "fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF_8" >> /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd opcache intl zip calendar dom mbstring zip gd xsl
RUN pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/

USER $user
```

Is there any point that I did not notice in the above files, and is there any solution to the following problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP 8.1, upgrade mongodb-odm to version 2.3. This is the first version to support PHP 8 as outlined in [this statement](https://www.doctrine-project.org/2021/12/04/mongodb-odm-2.3.html):

> We have released a new minor version 2.3 of Doctrine MongoDB ODM, the first version with support for using PHP 8 Attributes as a new driver for mapping documents and several other changes. [See all changes and contributors in the Changelog](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/releases/tag/2.3.0) on GitHub.

Otherwise, downgrade to PHP 7.0 as indicated in the error message.